# How to deploy laravel project on Server?

Tags: php, laravel

I built a linux server on digitialocean and installed require software and clone laravel files from github to /var/www/html/. I get this error

```
 "The 138.68.81.200 page isn’t working" in http://138.68.81.200/socialNetwork/public/
```

Even though uploading migrations and create .env files and storage/* 777 permission.

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: You have to point your default website to this folder if you want to access the website using the ip. What server are you using? (apache, nginx, ...)

Comment: I'm using apache2

Comment: Where you have code uploaded? Is it in `/var/www/html/socialNetwork` or `/var/www/socialNetwork` folder?

Comment: /var/www/html/socialNetwork/public

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have installed all php packages and dependencies and all project vendors via composer. You just need to add this to `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`

```
Alias /socialNetwork /var/www/html/socialNetwork/public/
<Directory "/var/www/html/socialNetwork/public">
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>
```

And then add this in your `/var/www/html/socialNetwork/public/.htaccess` :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

After that:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```